# How to place a posted value in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here in click.html,OnClick of clint_ip text box is redirecting to index.html.There we will select some client_ip's .After hitting the submit button in the index.html,I'm able to retrieve the values in the click.html.But I'm unable to keep the retrieved value into the client_ip textbox of click.html.I'm able to get the values in the "res" variable.

My click.html

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpryvkin/Plugins/master/pagination/simple_numbers_no_ellipses.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="clicDiv">
Client IP :<input type="text" id="ipClick"  onclick="getValue();" name="Client IP" />
</div>
<script>


function getUSERIP(){

if(!window.location.href.match(/client_ip=.*?([^\&])/))
   return;

var ip = window.location.href.match(/client_ip=.*?([^\&])/)[0].replace('client_ip=','');


$("#ipClick").val(ip);

}
getUSERIP();

function getValue(){
location.href='/home/divya/html_docs/index.html';

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpryvkin/Plugins/master/pagination/simple_numbers_no_ellipses.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#ip").val('');

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );

</script>

  </head>
  <body>

<div>
<form action="/home/divya/html_docs/click.html" method="get" >
Client_ip :<input type="text" id ="ip" name="client_ip" style="width: 600px;"/>
<div id="subDiv">
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</div></br>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</table>

   <script>

  var tabulate = function (data,columns) {
var svg = d3.select('#ip').append("svg")
  var table = d3.select('#example')
    var thead = table.append('thead')
    var tbody = table.append('tbody')

    thead.append('tr')
      .selectAll('th')
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
      .append('th')
        .text(function (d) { return d })

    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
      .append('tr')

    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function (column) {
                return { column: column, value: row[column] }
          })
      })
      .enter()
    .append('td')
   .text(function (d) { return d.value })
   .append("input")
   .attr("id","change")
   .attr("type", "checkbox")
   .style("float","left")
.on("click", function(d,i) { 

        var csv = $(':checkbox[id=change]:checked').map(function(){return $(this).parent().text();}).get().join(',');

        $('#ip').val(csv);

});

  return table;
}

d3.csv('some1.csv',function (data) {
    var columns = ['client_ip']
  tabulate(data,columns)
});
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a function for it and put this on click.html file

```
function getUSERIP(){

if(!window.location.href.match(/client_ip=.*?([^\&]+)/))
   return;
var ip = window.location.href.match(/client_ip=.*?([^\&]+)/)[0].replace('client_ip=','');

$("#ipClick").val(ip);

}
getUSERIP();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur suggestion.It really worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in yout getValue()function, you need to return res value.